# Solr 6.1 - Where is my collection's `managed-schema` file

Tags: solr, solr6

I am using Solr 6.1 on Windows 7.

I see my collection's files from the admin UI and it has a `managed-schema` file in there.

When I try to search (using Notepad++) my Solr directory with a line from the managed-schema file, it finds nothing.

I have also tried to change most (if not all) of the `managed-schema` files in the Solr directory and my changes are still not applied after reloading the core (and also the file contents of `managed-schema` in the admin UI remain unchanged).

Can someone explain to me what is this file that I see inside admin UI?
Is it a real file or a virtual one?

What I try to do -if that matters- is to make some fields not to be multiValued. It seems Solr likes making them all multiValued for some reason (the admin UI's `managed-schema` file contains some `<field name="fieldname" type="strings"/>` in it, so I think this is causing the problem - I will try using `string` there), so I am fighting to change its configuration. However, it seems that the file names, file paths, etc, etc are all changing from version to version. So, I can't even find the schema configuration path. Very confusing stuff. :(

Can anyone help?

**EDIT :**

Based on the fact that I cannot find a single `schema.xml` configuration file in my Solr folder, I guess this file is out of fashion now... I **guess** it makes no sense trying to use such a file in this version of Solr...

**UPDATE :**

After digging into places other than the (useless and misleading) documentation pages of Solr, I got these:

[https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-solr-user/201509.mbox/](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-solr-user/201509.mbox/%3CCAF2DzVVBH2bXRsYEoYnRvNL2TjFYdAHiJkAKCbiGAzWpiNec1Q@mail.gmail.com%3E)

[https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-solr-user/201509.mbox/](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-solr-user/201509.mbox/%3CCAN4YXvf+1A6JsuM3bsUs2Lo8Sst3HbJuihr0-Y6h4QjOr57RvQ@mail.gmail.com%3E)

So, if that's the real documentation right there, I guess I should first find a way to get the port that my zookeeper is listening and upload my configuration files there. Dandy, except for the fact that I don't see the ZooKepeer port listed ANYWHERE in the adminUI. I also didn't setup any ZooKeeper. I hope one exists by default... :(

**UPDATE 2 :**

https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCloud

> By default, an embedded Zookeeper server runs at the Solr port plus 1000, so 9983.

And that info seems to solve my job problems...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just rename managed-schema to **schema.xml.**
Then reload a core.

> If you have an existing Solr collection that uses
>   ClassicIndexSchemaFactory, and you wish to convert to use a managed
>   schema, you can simplify modify the solrconfig.xml to specify the use
>   of the ManagedIndexSchemaFactory. Once Solr is restarted and it
>   detects that a schema.xml file exists, but the
>   managedSchemaResourceName file (ie: "managed-schema") does not exist,
>   the existing schema.xml file will be renamed to schema.xml.bak and the
>   contents are re-written to the managed schema file. If you look at the
>   resulting file, you'll see this at the top of the page:

Please read carefully. 
**Switching from schema.xml to Managed Schema**

> An alternative to using a managed schema is to explicitly configure a
>   ClassicIndexSchemaFactory.  ClassicIndexSchemaFactory requires the use
>   of a schema.xml configuration file, and disallows any programatic
>   changes to the Schema at run time.  The schema.xml file must be edited
>   manually and is only loaded only when the collection is loaded.

```
<schemaFactory class="ClassicIndexSchemaFactory"/>
```

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Schema+Factory+Definition+in+SolrConfig

**Updated**:

Changing to Manually Edited schema.xml

If you have started Solr with managed schema enabled and you would like to switch to manually editing a schema.xml file, you should take the following steps:

1. Rename the managed-schema file to schema.xml. Modify solrconfig.xml
   to replace the schemaFactory class.
2. Remove any
       ManagedIndexSchemaFactory definition if it exists
3. Add a 
       ClassicIndexSchemaFactory definition as shown above Reload the
       core(s).

Comment: I will try that. But :
1) Is there any way to find the correct path for your collection's schema file? Because the only folder containing my collection's name is `\example\cloud\node2\solr\collection1_shard1_replica1` and there aren't any configs in there. :(
2) What's the difference between managed and classic schema? Is it so significant that I must switch to classic? Or I can keep the managed and use `<bool name="mutable">true</bool>` (or something similar) to make it work similarly to the classic one? Is managed updated automatically by Solr ?

Comment: @user2173353 ${solr.install.dir:.} - installation directory, solr.solr.home - all collections are here.Just open UI interface of Solr to see the settings. You should switch to classic otherwise you will gonna loose your changes after a core reload.As it will be complied.Solr starts with your schema.xml file and creates a new file called, by default, managed-schema to store all the inferred schema information. This file is automatically overwritten by Solr as it detects changes to the schema. Y

Comment: I saw that `solr.install.dir` pointed to a location where there was a folder with my collection/core name and one called `zoo_data`. I have placed a `schema.xml` file inside my core's folder (there was no schema file in there at all) and now (alter a Solr stop and re-start) the AdminUI is broken (it displays two red containers with no error message). Removing the added XML doesn't fix the problem. This thing gets broken very easily. I will reinstall the files, but I am still not 100% sure what breaks my Solr. :(

Comment: The XML was a `managed-schema` copy and only contained a change for adding the `<schemaFactory class="ClassicIndexSchemaFactory"/>` (there was no other schemaFactory  defined) and my field definitions. If I clear the whole XML and ONLY add the field definitions and the `schemaFactory`, will it work or I will destroy Solr once again? :(

Comment: That's the paths: `-Dsolr.install.dir=F:\Users\me\Downloads\solr-6.1.0 -Dsolr.solr.home=F:\Users\me\Downloads\solr-6.1.0\example\cloud\node1\solr`. And I put the XML inside `${Dsolr.solr.home}\collection1\ ` named as `schema.xml`.

Comment: Nope. Using a lighter XML destroys Solr too. I am so lost... Donno if I do something wrong when creating the collection: I first remove the default collection called `gettingstarted` and then I add a new core (there are no other cores at that point). That creates a collection as well. Everything seems fine, up until I put the XML inside `${Dsolr.solr.home}/collection1/`. Then Solr's adminUI totally stops working.

Comment: @user2173353 solr.install.dir.Dsolr.solr.home=F:\Users\me\Downloads\solr-6.1.0\example\cloud\node1\solr this is the right path for collections.Just go inside /your_core_name/conf/ and find file managed-schema, then rename it to schema.xml.Then restart a core.

Comment: @user2173353 try to create a new core from scratch and play with it.

Comment: The `conf` folder was missing. There was only a `data` folder and a `core.properties` file. Adding the folder `conf` and the XML inside it, once again, destroyed Solr (I cannot believe my own eyes. Solr gets destoyed wherever I put this file :o). Also, the cores that are created by default (`gettingstarted_shard1_replica1` and `gettingstarted_shard2_replica1`) lack a `conf` folder as well, so it's not only my own core that is weird. Maybe some new trend in this Solr version? I will try again...

Comment: @user2173353 Example of core structure: http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-zWmWPHKrmYA/URBOUoCYOLI/AAAAAAAAA8M/px33YlR5gCg/s1600/croppedLargeFontSolrDirectoryStructure.jpg

Comment: When I setup this structure as in the image, it seems that Solr becomes corrupted. No useful info on the log files. I have also tried creating the collection like that: `solr create -c collection1 -n collection1 -d "F:\Users\me\Downloads\solr-6.1.0\example\files\conf"` pointing to an existing folder with the desired `schema.xml` and still it uses `managed-schema` without my specified fields and my core's folder has no `conf` folder. If I try to put a `conf` folder on that collection is seems to ignore it. And it also ignores the original `conf` folder that I gave to it so... Nothing works. :(

Comment: https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-solr-user/201509.mbox/<CAF2DzVVBH2bXRsYEoYnRvNL2TjFYdAHiJkAKCbiGAzWpiNec1Q@mail.gmail.com>

Comment: What was wrong in my case was that I was running Solr in cloud mode, where one should upload the configuration to Zookeeper. :) When not in cloud mode, the configuration is on the file system.

Answer (score 1):

**In ubuntu: For version Solr 6.6.0 collections are stored in "/var/solr/data/collection_name"**